# reset.css and modernizr for Rails3.2 app

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, html5boilerplate, css-reset

I would like to add reset.css and modernizer.js to my new rails app however there are many different ways to do this. I heard HTML5 BoilerPlate has a reset.css and modernizer included but that the vast majority of it is not needed for rails. I've come across many options and am not sure which is the best option for my project.

I'm basically looking to make development on the front end as easy as possible. I'm not looking to support all browsers, just FF, Chrome, and IE from the past few versions. What css and js libraries would you recommend I use, and how would I add them to rails3.2?

Thank you

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ is pretty good

Comment: @sachleen, bootstrap is an idea, i just don't like the bar at the top. seems like everyone knows when a site uses bootstrap.